# SQL Server Agent fails when using sp_send_dbmail to execute a stored procedure containing a linked server

Tags: sql-server-agent, sp-send-dbmail

Starting July 1st, 2021, SQL Server Agent fails when using `sp_send_dbmail` to execute a stored procedure containing a linked server. If I remove the linked server portion of the code from the stored procedure the job runs successfully.
The job simply executes the following SQL statement:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients = 'My.Name@MyEmailAddress',
@subject = 'Daily Security Check',
@query = 'EXECUTE MyDatabase.sec.pr_LinkedServerQuery',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
```

I can successfully run this code manually from a query window while logged on as the Agent. But if I R-click the job and select “Start job at step…” the agent job fails. Also, if I edit the job by removing the dbmail procedure and simply run `EXECUTE MyDatabase.sec.pr_LinkedServerQuery` the agent job is successful. It is only when nested inside the dbmail procedure that it fails.  This job has previously run successfully for over a year.
I am using SQL Server 2017.

The logs show an error about `sp_send_dbmail` but searches on this error don’t seem to reflect the issue I am having.

> Executed as user: HCI\AgentName. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.3381.3 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:19:52 PM  Progress: 2021-07-06 14:19:52.96     Source: {457716A2-22BF-47F5-A08E-8A48A218911F}      Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Error: 2021-07-06 14:19:53.11     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Execute T-SQL Statement Task Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail       @recipients = '..." failed with the following error: "Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  Warning: 2021-07-06 14:19:53.11     Code: 0x80019002     Source: Subplan_1      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  Progress: 2021-07-06 14:19:53.16     Source: Notify Operator Task      Executing query "EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_notify_operator @name=N'Andy H...".: 100% complete  End Progress  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:19:52 PM  Finished: 2:19:54 PM  Elapsed:  1.719 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed

This issue has bested me so far. Thank you for any insight into slaying this beast!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ramya Makam for your [article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/mail-fails-with-sqlcmd-error).
After I ran the profiler I got a real error:

> Linked servers cannot be used under impersonation without a mapping for the impersonated login.

With that it was easy to edit Linked Servers and I am back up and running!